# Passing a <a> link name in Razor to an integrated site

Tags: asp.net, html, razor

I would like to grab the name of the  link from my menu in the layoutsite and pass it to my content site. To embed different sites depending on the name that is passed after clicking on the menu option, but only need to link to one page.

This is the menu of my layout-site:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="cat1"><a href="~/">Startseite</a></li>
  <li class="cat2"><a href="">Karten &amp; Pläne</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a name="mapGuide" href="~/Menue/menueoptions.cshtml">MapGuide (neu)</a></li>
      <li><a name="mapDuideOld" href="~/Menue/menueoptions.cshtml">MapGuide (alt)</a></li>
      <li><a name ="cad" href="~/Menue/menueoptions.cshtml">CAD Plan Archiv</a></li>
      <li><a name ="sewer" href="~/Menue/menueoptions.cshtml">Kanalsystem</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thats still part of the layout-site where to content-site will be integrated:

```
<div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
```

This is my content-site:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "";

var menu = this.Request.name;

@functions{
    private String forward;
}

if (menu == "mapGuide")
{
    forward = "http://xxxxxxxxx";
}
else if (menu == "mapGuideOld")
{
    forward = "http://xxxxxxxxxx";
} 
and so on ...
}

<embed class="pdf" src="@forward">
```

It's almost working because if i manually type in the name at the section:

```
var menu = mapGuide;
```

it links perfectly .... the problem is only, all the time ^^
I hope there is a solution for my problem, would be greatly appreciated ;)

cheers Kuli

Comment: You can do something like `var menu = Request.QueryString["page"];` and construct your URLs like `~/Menue/menueoptions.cshtml?page=mapGuide`

Comment: Well thank you very much ! ... It is working just fine although I was maybe looking for a way to do it, without adding additional stuff to the URL. .... Nevertheless its working ;)